# Unable to Ping Smartphones Using Java

Tags: java, router, ping, smartphone

I'm currently making a Java application that detects when smartphones connect to our home network. I'm able to get the IP addresses of all of the "remembered" devices on the network, ping the devices currently active on the network like desktops and laptops, but when I try to ping smartphones (either from command line or from the Java application using the InetAddress's isReachable() method) the requests time out.

Is this a problem with a security setting on our router? Do the phones (iPhones) themselves have security that prevents this? Is there any other Java code I can use to detect when these smartphones are or aren't active on the network? I haven't been able to find a particularly helpful answer so far in previous questions.

Thank you for reviewing my question!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863333/is-there-a-way-to-ping-an-iphone-to-see-if-its-turned-on

Answer (score 0):

It might be a good idea to inspect your network with [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), or with an other similar software to see what is going on behind the scenses on your neteork. If you use linux, you may want to try the unix command `arp-scan`, which does network discovery for you.